# error while trying vaadin jpacontainer example

Tags: vaadin

I'm getting 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter$ConversionException`
error. I have made `Person` class as entity, and my application class is like this:

```
public class SimplejpaApplication extends Application  {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        JPAContainer<Person> persons =
        JPAContainerFactory.make(Person.class, "book-examples");
        persons.addEntity(new Person("Marie-Louise Meilleur", 117));
        Table personTable = new Table("The Persistent People",persons);
        layout.addComponent(personTable);

        setMainWindow(new Window("simple",layout));
    }
```

I'm using **vaadin-jpacontainer-agpl-3.0-3.0.0-alpha2.jar**
Can someone tell why this error happening? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Converter](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha2/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/util/converter/Converter.html) class is from Vaadin 7 but you are using Vaadin 6. You need to use vaadin-jpacontainer-agpl-3.0-2.1.0 for Vaadin 6.

Or you can upgrade your project to Vaadin 7 and use vaadin-jpacontainer-agpl-3.0-3.0.0-alpha2.jar.

Both jar files can be downloaded from Vaadin add-on page https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-jpacontainer.